# tkinter image not found when button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an instance of a button that uses two images to represent a 2-way valve in on or off state.

The path for both images works because I can initialized the button with either image.

I have made references to both images and made the variables global and I still get "_tkinter.TclError: image "vbon" doesn't exist"

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

toggleA = 0
global vboncopy, vboffcopy, vbon, vboff
root = Tk()
root.title("ICP")
root.geometry('200x125')

def valve_A():
     global toggleA
     if toggleA == 0:
         toggleA = 1
         #vbon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/mu_code/images/Black80x40VbuttonON.jpg"), master=root)
         ValveA['image'] = 'vbon'
         #ValveA.configure(image='vbon')
         #ValveA = Button(root, image=vbon, command = valve_A())        
     else:
         toggleA = 0
         #vboff = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/mu_code/images/Black80x40VbuttonOFF.jpg"), master=root)
         ValveA['image'] = 'vboff'
         #ValveA.configure(image='vboff')
         #ValveA = Button(root, image=vboff, command = valve_A())

global vboncopy, vboffcopy, vbon, vboff
vbon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/mu_code/images/Black80x40VbuttonON.jpg"), master=root)
vboncopy = vbon
vboff = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/mu_code/images/Black80x40VbuttonOFF.jpg"), master=root)
vboffcopy = vboff

ValveA = Button(root, bd= -2, image=vboff, command = lambda: valve_A())
ValveA.grid(row=0, column=0, padx='12',pady='5')

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the complete error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/mu_code/StackOverflow.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    ValveA = Button(root, bd= -2, image=vboff, command = lambda: valve_A())
  File "/home/pi/mu_code/StackOverflow.py", line 15, in valve_A
    ValveA['image'] = 'vbon'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1492, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "vbon" doesn't exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mu_code/StackOverflow.py", line 34, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1283, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this code:

```
ValveA['image'] = 'vbon'
```

It's not doing what you think it's doing. It's trying to set the `image` option to the four-byte *string* "vbon". There is no image with that as a name.

This is how you should reference the image:

```
ValveA['image'] = vbon
```

---

FWIW, `vboncopy` and `vboffcopy` are not *copies* - they are just different references for the same image.